Compositor - Disable rotation of streaks with camera rotation in Glare node?
Is there a way in the compositor to get the streaks added to bright objects (stars here) using the glare node to stay at a set angle in the scene, rather than maintain the angle that the camera is at?
I have an astrophotograph, where I have stars with diffraction spikes in the image already and I always like some rotation in my camera animation, but the image stars will stay fixed obviously whereas composited streaks on 3D stars will move which will look weird, so I’d like composited streaks to remain static.

You can animate the angle property. If you know the rotation of the camera you can adjust it at the same pace to simulate a fixed angle

Thank you! I did not realise that was possible
